# How to display blocks in multiple rows in XSL-FO?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to add images in multiple rows.

Here is my code:

```
<fo:block-container reference-orientation="90" >
    <xsl:for-each select="Icons/Icon">
        <fo:block>
            <fo:external-graphic src="{@Source}"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:block-container>
```

The `<fo:block-container>` is placed in an `<fo:table-cell>`.

You can see examples below where text is other part of the table.

How it looks:

[image: current result]

But it should look like this:

[image: desired result]

I tried to add width for block-container, but it doesn't help.

Comment: It might help to know how the "Pleat filtro cla.." text is placed where we see it

Comment: @StefanHegny, question is updated.

Comment: @StefanHegny, I would like to setup max width for the block-container, so we don't have to know other details of this document.

Answer (score 1):

It can't wrap because you're using a rotated `fo:block-container`, so what you're seeing is the rotated equivalent of blocks overflowing past the bottom of the page.

It's not clear to me why you're rotating the images, but you could put each graphic inside a separate `fo:inline-container` and set the `reference-orientation` on each. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container)

```
<fo:table-cell>
  <fo:block>
    <fo:inline-container reference-orientation="90">
      <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic src="..." />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
    ...
  </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Comment: I didn't realize these images are rotated (because they all look similar in any rotation), so my question is incorrect. Thanks for the help.